# Spring MVC Custom Validation with external configuration

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

My application is based on Spring MVC.and have more than 200 jsp pages.Each jsp page have average 100 fields.

For Server side validations I am using spring validator. org.springframework.validation.Validator
ValidationUtils.reject etc

My model/bean class are Jaxb class, **So I am not using Bean/Model level annotated based javax and hibernate validator**(javax.validation.constraints. and org.hibernate.validator.constraints.).

***Now problem is lines of codes etc***. For ex: one form have 100 fields, and each filed have minimum 3 validations (mandatory, digit, range etc).Than 300 lines of code with all if/else blocks.

I am planning to use some external configuration such as Properties file, rule file or db. So I can configure all validation for each filed and that configuration will be input to my spring validator class.

Please suggest help, how to handle this type of situations.Please share your thoughts, any implemntions , code, links etc.

Thanks
Manu

Comment: 200 page of 100 field each?What kind of software is that.Sounds like a lot of duplication to me; let alone fitting 100 field in one screen..

Comment: 200 different jsp pages,These are online forms.For users to fill up and submit.And each form have around 100 fields.

Comment: I hope I don't encounter one of your online forms mate. It would be a pain answering 100 fields.

Comment: One of form have 236 fields :-(. that why form data storing in xml and the models are jaxb class